# How to mock an object into the Application class of android in a test-case?

Tags: android, unit-testing, automated-tests, mockito

I am testing [Using `UI Automator`] a particular task, where a thread is started when the application class is created. [`onCreate()`].

Now, I have mocked the entire thread which makes a http call to series of tasks that happen inside the app. [`mockedThread`]

Now, I use a variable to access this object when `TEST=true` and run in the normal mode where a http call is made when `TEST=false`. I make TEST=true only inside the test methods.

Right now the code works in this way -

```
onCreate() {

  if TEST == true {
    use mock object and update it manually.
    -- mockedObject
  } else if TEST == false {
    use real object and update it using http calls.
    -- real Object 
  }
}
```

Now I'm trying to use the mocked object `without this if -- else loop of testing = TRUE or FALSE`. Is there any was we can do this with **mockito** or any other way... like **dagger2** or something ?
[PS: Please don't advise on Powermock as these are not static object]

I am trying to mock it like this but doesn't work :

```
testMock() {
 try {
   AndroidApplication application = Mockito.mock(AndroidApplication.class);
   context.startActivity(intent);
   mDevice.wait(Until.hasObject(By.pkg(TARGET_PACKAGE).depth(0)), Constants.LAUNCH_TIMEOUT);
            Mockito.when(application.getThreadObject()).thenReturn(mockObject);
 } catch(MockException m){
    m.printStackTracke();
 }
}
```

Error I get it - **Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.**

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're mocking (more specifically I don't understand what you mean by mockedThread), but generally, if you can inject the object with dagger, you can provide a test version for it, where a mock gets injected into the application instead of the real object.

Comment: I have the Application class where I start a thread. this makes http calls to get data and update global objects which will be used in activities when they are opened. 
Now, I am trying to mock this thread in the application class where it will get objects from local and update the global objects to be used in the activities.

Comment: I used injection of object rather than mocking it. I make a interface A and made a class AA and mock class AB in testing package and injected AB instead of AA while the App is opening to not make http calls but use the results given by AB. This suits perfectly for my scenario !